# VBA. Excel Filter Criteria value passed through a function

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a filtering (and copy) option using a custom sub routine written using VBA. The subroutine gets the category to be filtered, as a parameter 'catName'. 
I tried setting this to the criteria, using multiple combinations but the filtering is not happening.

Try 1

```
copyRange.AutoFilter 9, Criteria1:=catName
```

Try 2

```
Dim crit As String
crit = "=" & chr(34)&catName&chr(34)
```

Try 3

```
crit = "'" & catName& "'"
```

All the above failed.

How ever if I just hard code a category name in the code it is working fine.

```
copyRange.AutoFilter 9, Criteria1:="B"
```

How can I use the value passed into the function be used as the criteria? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass criteria a bit like formula. Try with this:

```
copyRange.AutoFilter 9, Criteria1:="=" & catName
```

Equation mark is important here!

Comment: Why is it important? I can manage pretty well without the `=`.

Comment: This worked. And to make sure that I do not have a any leading of trailing spaces, I just made it into:-
`Criteria1:="=" & Trim(catName)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim catName As String
catName = "B"
copyRange.AutoFilter 9, Criteria1:=catName
```

You are not referencing somewhere correctly or you are not defining the `catName` correctly. E.g., check how it is done, filtering on column 1 by "3":

[image]

when using this code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim copyRange   As Range
    Dim strFilter   As String

    Set copyRange = Range("A1:P10")
    strFilter = "3"
    copyRange.AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=strFilter

End Sub
```